# How I can get the placeholder from an input in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing

Grettings...

I am trying to write a test and I need to get the placeholder text from input to verify if this is the expected string or not.

For instance:

```
const stringInput = () => $('#input_field')
```

I need a method like

```
stringInput().getPlaceholderText().includes('expected text')
```

Thanks for your attention.

P/D: The page is built with React.js

Comment: Just FYI that placeholder text is not accessible and should not be used as a label.

Comment: It is not used as a label, it is a text input field. But the test must confirm that the placeholder contains the expected text and not something else. So, it's impossible to get the placeholder text?

Answer (score 0):

Store reference to element and then get attribute placeholder.

```
const ref = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
   const placeholder = ref.current.getAttribute("placeholder")
}, [ref])

return (
   <input ref={ref}> 
)
```

```js
const input = document.getElementById("input");

const placeholder = input.getAttribute("placeholder");

console.log(placeholder);
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="default value" id="input"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

it depends on when you want to get the placeholder value, for example, if you need to get it on input focus, you can use this :

```js
let PlaceHolderValue = "";
const getPlaceHolder = (e) => {PlaceHolderValue  = e.target.placeholder }

<input
type="text"
name="user_name"
placeholder="Name"
onFocus={getPlaceHolder} />
```

the placeholder value will be stored in the PlaceHolderValue variable!